# Oh-My-ZSH in italian, I want english

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

my Oh-My-ZSH returns error messages and dates etc. in italian, instead of english.
the only thing I could find about this online

`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

which I added to my .zshrc, to no result.

working on CentOS (linux)..

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LC_ALL` instead:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and check if it changed correctly with:

```
locale
```